# StackTrace Remote 

Tags: android, exception

I have written two pieces of code one for send email and other for collecting stacktrace if FORCE ERROR occurs , and both of these code work individually . 
Now my problem is when i club both of these code it doesnt work (log are also working normal)

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

public Context context;


public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {

        Writer result = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
        paramThrowable.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        System.out.println("BaseActivity.onCreate(...).new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {...}.uncaughtException()" +result.toString());
        sendMail(result.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"cs", 1).show();
        }
    });
}

public void sendMail(String body){
    try {
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("email@gmail.com",
                "password");
        sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.silverSkills.com/com.silverSkills.com.ChildActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException" +
                "at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)" +
                "   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)" +
                "   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)" +
                "   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)" +
                "   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)" +
                "   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)" +
                "   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)" +
                "   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)" +
                "   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)" +
                "   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)" +
                "   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)" +
                "   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)" +
                " Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" +
                "   at com.silverSkills.com.ChildActivity.onCreate(ChildActivity.java:9)" +
                "   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)" +
                "   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)" +
                "   ... 11 more",
                "email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com");

        Log.i("Confirm","mail send");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

}

And this is how call make call this code .

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContext(this);
    String a=null;
    a.toString();
}
```

It would be great if u can suggest me anything  :D

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel and not use something like [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)?

Comment: ACRA contains a lots of stuff ..plus ACRA lib size is 450Kb and my app   size is only 300KB so it dnt make me any size to increase my apk as my   app get updated very frequently on a very slow GPRS network . I would be great if u help me little bit

Comment: If you're using proguard, it removes a lot of unused code and therefore shrinks the library significantly.

Comment: Can you please check what is the issue with this code ..